# C++ map[]= memory ramifications

Tags: c++, memory

Let's say you have an unordered instance variable map that maps an integer to an object (like a time object). 
If you are overwriting that map and you use the standard overwrite like map_[5] = time.now() in a class function, where is that time.now object created? Is it in the stack where the function was and so when the function goes out of scope that time in the map goes out of scope? Or is it with the class objects so you can check that time later?

Basically, if you are writing to an instance field map in one function and you are storing objects you want to access later can you use normal objects or do you need to use pointers?

I haven't used C++ for a while and I'm trying to relearn the nuances and this is really confusing me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifetime of objects contained in a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` is the lifetime of the map.  Keep in mind though that the object you assign to an element of a map isn't the same object as the one contained in the map.

---

For example, in this snippet:

```
std::map<int, std::chrono::system_clock::time_point> my_map;
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
my_map[10] = now;
```

There are actually at least two `time_point` objects involved:

1. `now`
2. `my_map[10]`

The line `my_map[10] = now` actually does quite a bit:

1. Since no value exists in `my_map` for the key `10`, `map::operator[]` default-constructs a new `time_point` object, inserts it into `my_map`, and returns a reference to it.
2. The the assignment operator function of the returned `time_point` object is called and passed a reference to `now`.
3. `time_point::operator=` adjusts the state of the `time_point` it was called on to mirror the state of the `time_point` passed to it.

It's the `time_point` object that's stored in the map whose lifetime is controlled by the map.  `now` is a local variable, and as such its lifetime will end at the end of the scope in which it was declared.

---

For example, given the following class definition:

```
class Foo {
public:
    const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& do_a_thing(int i);
private:
    std::map<int, std::chrono::system_clock::time_point> my_map;
};
```

The following definition of `do_a_thing` is invalid:

```
const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& do_a_thing(int i) {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    my_map[i] = now;
    return now;  // whoops, returning a reference to a function local
}
```

while the following is valid:

```
const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& do_a_thing(int i) {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    my_map[i] = now;
    return my_map[i]; // OK, the lifetime of my_map[i] is the same as my_map
}
```